# using underscore templates with backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I'm trying to create a page using backbone.js and underscore.js.  I want the page to have a button, that when pressed, adds the contents of a form to an empty  tag on the page using a template that I have defined.

Here's my empty tag where I want the template stuff to go after the button is pressed:

```
<div id="playView"></div>
<input type="button" id="addQuestion" value="Add Question" />
```

Here's my template where the form data should go:

```
<script id="viewTemplate" type="text/template">
   <div id="stemView">{{ Stem }}</div>
    <label for="answer1"> a)</label><div>{{ answer1View }}</div>
    <label for="answer2"> b)</label><div>{{ answer2View }}</div>
    <label for="answer3"> c)</label><div>{{ answer3View }}</div>
    <label for="answer4"> d)</label><div>{{ answer4View }}</div>
</script>
```

And here's the form that the user will fill out:

```
<form>
    <textarea id="stem"><textarea>
    <textarea id="answer1"></textarea>
    <textarea id="answer2"></textarea>
    <textarea id="answer3"></textarea>
    <textarea id="answer4"></textarea>
</form>
```

And here is the relevant backbone.js code.  My question is, what do I do in the event?  How do I get the data from the form, then into the viewTemplate, and then into the empty div tag(playView)?

```
wizard.PlayView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.model.bind('change', _.bind(this.render, this));
    },
    el: '#playView',

    events: {
        'click button#addQuestion': 'addQuestion'
    }
    addQuestion: function () {
        $(this.el).append();
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the template library that you are using ? The syntax looks like Handlebars

Comment: underscore but I changed the template rules to use {{ }}

Comment: Sort-of off-topic but, If your using Backbone version > 0.9.0. You can use `this.$el` instead of `$(this.el)` to reference your view element. Also, you can use `this.model.on('change',this.render,this)` to supply a context for your callback. `bind` is an alias for `on`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, the way you have this setup now, you will not be able to trigger

```
   events: {
        'click button#addQuestion': 'addQuestion'
    }
```

because the input tag needs to be in the backbone template. So to fix this problem, the black bone template will render the button on the page, then listen for the click on the button. When the button is clicked, you will load the question template (which is embedded in the html page and insert that into the current backbone template.

```
<script id="viewTemplate" type="text/template">
   <div id="stemView">{{ Stem }}</div>
    <label for="answer1"> a)</label><div>{{ answer1View }}</div>
    <label for="answer2"> b)</label><div>{{ answer2View }}</div>
    <label for="answer3"> c)</label><div>{{ answer3View }}</div>
    <label for="answer4"> d)</label><div>{{ answer4View }}</div>
</script>

<script id="mainTemplate" type="text/template">
  <input type="button" id="addQuestion" value="Add Question" />
</script>


wizard.PlayView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.model.bind('change', _.bind(this.render, this));
    },

el: '#playView',

template : _.template($('#mainTemplate').html())

events: {
    'click button#addQuestion': 'addQuestion'
}

addQuestion: function () {
    var t = _.template($('#stemTemplate').html();
    $(this.el).append(t(this.model.toJSON()));
}

 render: function() {
            $(this.el).append(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
       }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.  So your code would fix my event?  So whenever the 'addQuestion' button is pressed, the viewTemplate will be populated with the data from the form, which will then populate playView. Thanks

Comment: My code will fix the event, and trigger it. At that point, it as simple as inserting html into your template with a jQuery.append()

Answer (score 1):

You would first build the model that contains the data.

Then inside the view, you would compile the template first

Use `_.template` to compile the template

```
   wizard.PlayView = Backbone.View.extend({
        template : _.template($('#viewTemplate').html())
        initialize: function () {
        // Use listenTo to bind events instead of directly 
        // listening on the model
            this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
        },
        events: {
            'click .addQuestion': 'addQuestion'
        },
        addQuestion: function(e) {
            var $target = $(e.target);
            // Your logic here
        },
        render: function() {
            $(this.el).append(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
       }
```

Then inside the render of the view you would pass in the model along with the compiled template, which would get populated with the data inside the model.

Comment: Oh ok, so I get the data in my model.  But what about the button event? Do I not need that now?  Thanks

Comment: @999cm999.. Create  a events hash and add the event in it. Should be good.. And I believe you might be having 1 button for each form view. So use `class` instead of an `id` as ID should be unique.. Check updated post